# Upload the image and save it to local project folder

Tags: java, angularjs, spring, image-uploading

i'm developing a user registration page, in this page i have to upload user's image.later selected image has to save in my local project folder, and file path is going to database. how can i upload the image to local project folder.

Technologies used: AngularJS, Java Spring framework, Tomcat server

Comment: have u solved this..?

Answer (score 0):

you can use ng-file-upload (https://github.com/danialfarid/ng-file-upload, check also its examples section) module

examples:
  https://github.com/danialfarid/ng-file-upload/wiki/spring-mvc-example
  http://javatutorials.io/java-core/upload-file-angular-ng-file-upload/

Comment: i'm doing image upload according to this tutorial https://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-rs/file-upload-example-in-jersey/

Comment: see full reference https://github.com/danialfarid/ng-file-upload/blob/master/README.md#full-reference, you need to trigger upload function which will post your file/files to your server. In the full reference this function is called 'upload', you can use any name. This function may be triggered by selecting file from HTML: <input type="file" ngf-select="upload($files)"> or from <div type="file" ngf-drop="upload($files)"></div> (on DROP). There are plenty of configurations for validations, etc.... see continue in the next commit

Comment: Then you need to implement upload() function: https://github.com/danialfarid/ng-file-upload/blob/master/README.md#upload-service, actually passing your URL and your file in data params, see example http://angular-file-upload.appspot.com/js/upload.js (search for 'function uploadUsingUpload(file, resumable)'). , or check simpler example at https://github.com/danialfarid/ng-file-upload/wiki/spring-mvc-example, where you will also find JAVA code